# Dynamic Loader in Kendo Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile, kendo-ui-grid

I am trying to add combo box loader in kendo grid filter using this link
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/filtering/#toc-server-side-filtering
I am getting invalid template error.My use case is I need to have multi combobox in filter,so that user can select multiple entries using api call.
I am quite new to this,any help how we can achieve this.

Sample Code:

```
 $(function(){
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: products,
          filterable:    true,
          height: 400,
          columns: [
            {field: "CategoryName",
          filterable: {
                multi:true,
                 itemTemplate: function(e) {
                    return '<my-app> <span class="k-icon k-i-loading" style="color: #ff6358"></span> </my-app>'
                }
            }
            }]        
            });
        });
```

Comment: The link you provided is relevant to Kendo UI for Angular. However, the code seems to be from Kendo UI for jQuery.

Comment: @Giannis-Ok,actualy we are using what I have written in code,can it be possible to provide custom filter in kendogrid there so that user can filter and this will trigger api call and show records and then user can select multiple records

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with that. I'm just updating the tags to be accurate and you have more chances to find a solution.